# Solve $1 + 3^{x/2} = 2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve $1 + 3^{x/2} = 2^x$.

I tried to replace $3^{x/2}$ with $2^{\log_2(3) * x/2}$
Also I tried to use derivatives, saying that $x=2$ is a root, and then comparing the derivatives of the two sides, but this did not work.

Comment: You are trying to solve $$a^x+b^x=1$$ for $$a=\frac12\qquad b=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$ Since $a$ and $b$ are both in $(0,1)$, the LHS is strictly decreasing, from $+\infty$ when $x\to-\infty$ to $0$ when $x\to+\infty$, passing by $1$ when $x=2$, hence your proof is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the equation as
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^x=1.
$$
and note that the LHS is strictly decreasing as $0<1/2<1$ and $0<\sqrt{3}/2<1$ . Hence the equation has at most one solution. It is clear that $x=2$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\cos60^\circ)^x+(\sin60^\circ)^x=1$$

Now for $0<u<90^\circ,$

Can you prove

$$(\cos u)^m+(\sin u)^m$$ is decreasing function so that the solution is unique

Comment: Interesting how you apply trigonometry everywhere. +1

Comment: @samjoe, Thanks.  Do u notice any mistake here?

Comment: Not at all. But i think we can say generally $a^x$ is decreasing for $0<a < 1$

Answer (score 0):

put x = 2 in above expression . $1+3^{\frac{2}{2}} = 1+3^1 = 4$

$2^2 = 4 $

$x = 2 $ is a solution

Comment: Never mind, sorry about the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 2 y$ then the equation becomes
$$f(y)=4^y - 3^y = 1$$
for which only $y=1$ is the only solution. This leads to $x = 2$ as the only solution of the desired equation, since $f(y)$ will only increase as $y$ increases

Comment: best answer that shows $x=2$ is the only answer

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy This answer does not prove anything. It only slightly changed the equation with no added information about it. Other answers proved it because they use facts about strictly decreasing/increasing functions.

Comment: @user236182 respectfully disagree.  This argument is the shortest and clearest of any of them, while also taking a problem out of $\mathbb{R}$ and into $\mathbb{N}$.  It's also easier to see that the stated difference would increase as $y$ increases versus seeing that your sum would decrease as $x$ increases.  It's more intuitive.  While both are good proofs, I believe this one is superior because it's clearer which is why he received my +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also divide both sides by $(\sqrt{3})^x$.

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^x+1=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^x$$

$0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<1$ and $1<\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, so the left side is strictly decreasing and the right side is strictly increasing, so the equation has at most one solution and $x=2$ is a solution.